# How to make structured data items in set merge into groups?

Tags: algorithm, grouping, data-manipulation, data-processing

**Here is the condition:**

As I have a set of items, the items are instances of same class which contains properties that each of them has limited possible values.

For example, the class has 2 properties(p1,p2) which each of them has 2 values(A,B/1,2), there are only 4 kind of instances: { p1: "A", p2: 1 }, { p1: "A", p2: 2 }, { p1: "B", p2: 1 }, { p1: "B", p2: 2 }

To display an item by string, item { p1: "A", p2: 1 } will become "itemA1" and { p1: "B", p2: 2 } is "itemB2".

Therefore the set with unique items has 16 possibilities, from empty set ( [ ] ) to the universal set ( [ { p1: "A", p2: 1 }, { p1: "A", p2: 2 }, { p1: "B", p2: 1 }, { p1: "B", p2: 2 } ] ).

When it comes to display the set, if the set contains items with all possible values in one property and same values in others, the property will be concealed.

For example, set [ { p1: "A", p2: 1 }, { p1: "A", p2: 2 } ] contains all possible values in p2 with same value in p1. It will be displayed as "itemA", p2 is concealed.

Vice versa, [ { p1: "A", p2: 2 }, { p1: "B", p2: 2 } ] shows "item2".

The universal set [ { p1: "A", p2: 1 }, { p1: "A", p2: 2 }, { p1: "B", p2: 1 }, { p1: "B", p2: 2 } ] is only "item".

And with ungroupable items, set [ { p1: "A", p2: 1 }, { p1: "A", p2: 2 }, { p1: "B", p2: 2 } ] displays "itemA&B2" or "item2&A1", which is configurable.

**Here comes the problem:**

What is a good algorithm to realize these rules with more properties and values that might looks like { p1: 1|2, p2: 1|2|3, p3: 1|2|3, p4: 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9 }?

Currently I only thought out of looping each values with other properties fixed, making subsets, and display each subset. But it seems to be looping so many times and there will be so many subsets. Nevertheless I have to make an priority order to decide which possible subsets will be used.

This is a complicated question to me though it seems to be a basic problem.

If anybody has interest in this question, that will be good. Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 0):

How about following the below steps?

```
groups = getAllCombinations()
# getAllCombinations() implementation could recursively generate all combinations. 
# For example, for class has 2 properties(p1,p2), 
# we will have: groups = [ A1, A2, B1, B2 ]

# Loop the below for all class properties [p1, p2]
# Loop through the list of property values[A, B]
for p in properties: 
    combinations = getPropertyCombinations(p) 
    # This should return all combinations by keeping the given property constant.
    # For 'A' it will return 'A1', 'A2'; For 'B' it will return 'B1', 'B2'
    if all combinations in groups:
        #remove all combinations and insert the property
        for item in combinations:
            strItem = str(item)  
            # class item { p1: "A", p2: 1 } will have 'A1' returning str(item)
            groups.remove(strItem)
        groups.add(p)

#Your resulting groups will have resulting group by as per requirement.
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can not get your idea clear.

As my understanding with your code, the set [ { p1: "A", p2: 1 }, { p1: "A", p2: 2 }, { p1: "B", p2: 2 } ] will go through this steps:

groups = [ A1, A2, B1, B2 ];

remove A1 form groups;

remove A2 form groups;

remove B2 form groups;

So in the final the groups become [ B1 ].

As per specification, the result should be "A" with "B2" or "2" with "A1".

How do the groups variable lead into that expected result?

Comment: You are right, I missed that part. Probably the above code might help. For 2 properties it will easily work. The outer for loop for all the properties is a bit tricky. You also need to maintain the level of the property to generate combinations.   Core idea is the eliminate properties from the list 1 by 1. In above case, we eliminate the property p2 with p1 A value by removing A1, A2 and pushing A to the group again. property B2 will never be removed as the entire combinations is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use queue data structure to help you reduce the elements at each dimension.

**Algorithm:**

```
1. Loop through all items in the given set
      - generate strings for each item in an array
# After this loop, the set [ { p1: "A", p2: 1 }, { p1: "A", p2: 2 }, { p1: "B", p2: 2 } ]
# will have generate something like: items = ['A1','A2','B2']

2. Sort the array. #this is important to keep the order when reducing dimensions

3. Enqueue(put) all elements in 'Queue'

4. Dequeue(get) set of elements from 'Queue' such that last-1 index of string is same. # effectively we will get all A's then B's

5. If the count of elements in this set matches max elements for this case. We have identified a reduction. So, take 1 element in the set remove last index. Enqueue(put) it in the 'Queue' again

6. Else, add all elements to the 'Group' list.

7. Repeat steps 4-6 till the queue is empty.

8. 'Group' list will have the results as per requirement.
```

This algorithm will run in O(n * m). Where n is no.of elements in set and m is the no.of properties.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [Arun Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377711/arun-kumar)'s solution suggestion.

My solution for 2 properties with 2 values each is:

```js
/* pseudo-javascript-ish code */

// prepare data
properties = [ p1, p2 ]

values = { p1: [A,B], p2: [1,2] }

// groups
property_combinations = [ [], [p2], [p1], [p1,p2] ]

// combinations
value_combinations = [
  [ [A1], [A2], [B1], [B2] ], // []
  [ [A1,B1], [A2,B2] ],       // [p2]
  [ [A1,A2], [B1,B2] ],       // [p1]
  [ [A1,A2,B1,B2] ]           // [p1,p2]
]

// groups and combination could be generated by a function

function getSetItemString ( data ) {

  subgroups = []

  nest:
  for( i = value_combinations.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){

    for( j = 0; j < value_combinations[i].length; j++ ){

      // matching items, find if data contains the combination
      if( data.contains( value_combinations[i][j] ) ){

        // remove matched items from data and add it to subgroups
        data.removeItemsIn( value_combinations[i][j] )
        subgroups.push( value_combinations[i][j] )

      }

      if( data.length == 0 ){ break nest }

    }

  }

  // some function make the subgroups into string
  return subgroup.toItemString()

}

getItemString( [ A1, A2, B1 ] )
// returns itemA&B1

// flow:
// subgroup [p1,p2]
// [ A1, A2, B1 ] not match [A1,A2,B1,B2]

// subgroup [p1]
// [ A1, A2, B1 ] matches [A1,A2] => subgorup = [ [A1,A2] ]; set = [ B1 ]
// [ B1 ] not match [B1,B2]

// subgroup [p2]
// [ B1 ] not match [A1,B1]
// [ B1 ] not match [A2,B2]

// subgroup []
// [ B1 ] not match [A1]
// [ B1 ] not match [A2]
// [ B1 ] matches [B1] => subgroup = [ [A1,A2], [B1] ]; set = [ ]
// [ ] breaks the loop

// output
// [ [A1,A2], [B1] ] => itemA&B1
```

The complexity is related to the generation of combination matrix and matching items with given set.

But it is a little complex for me to calculate the precise number of complexity, it seems to be large.

The subgroup order is related to the order in the value_combinations.

To generate the combination matrix with more properties and values, I finally come up with this function:

```js
function createItemCombinations(structure){ // input example: {p1: ["A","B"], p2: [1,2,3], p3: ["+","-"]}
  let props = Object.keys(structure),
      prop_combs = nm( props.map(p => 1) ).map(ps => ps.reduce((r,v,p) => r.concat(v? props[p] : []), [])),
      value_combs = prop_combs.map(sub => {
        let mutable = Object.entries(structure).reduce((r,[p,vs]) => {
              if(sub.indexOf(p) == -1){
                return Object.assign(r, {[p]: vs})
              }else{
                return r
              }
            }, {}),
            immutable = Object.entries(structure).reduce((r,[p,vs]) => {
              if(sub.indexOf(p) != -1){
                return Object.assign(r, {[p]: vs})
              }else{
                return r
              }
            }, {}),
            mu_keys = Object.keys(mutable),
            im_keys = Object.keys(immutable),
            mu_combs = nm( mu_keys.map(k => mutable[k].length - 1) ).map(m => m.reduce((r,v,i) => Object.assign(r, {[mu_keys[i]]: mutable[mu_keys[i]][v]}), {})),
            im_combs = nm( im_keys.map(k => immutable[k].length - 1) ).map(m => m.reduce((r,v,i) => Object.assign(r, {[im_keys[i]]: immutable[im_keys[i]][v]}), {}))
        return im_combs.map(im => {
          return { items: mu_combs.map(mu => Object.assign({}, mu, im)), subgroup: Object.assign({}, im) }
        })
      })
  return value_combs
}
// nm is a function which receives an array like [1,1,1] which mean 3 properties with 2 values each, and returns an array with all combinations in indexes like [ [0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0], ... [1,1,1] ].
```